# Using Replace with

Tags: replacement

I have an expression

```
    expr=Derivative[1][A][\[Zeta]] + Derivative[2][A][\[Zeta]] + 
 Derivative[3][A][\[Zeta]] + Derivative[4][A][\[Zeta]]
```

I want to replace with the following:

[image]

where `n>=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
expr /. {
Derivative[i_ /; i>=2&&EvenQ[i]][A][\[Zeta]] -> P [\[Zeta]], 
Derivative[i_ /; i>=2&&OddQ[i]][A][\[Zeta]] -> P' [\[Zeta]]}
```

$A'(\zeta )+P'(\zeta )+2 P(\zeta )$